# conditional formatting of from_unixtime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that among other fields returns a due date and cutoff date. sometimes these field would be null and so, when converted like so:

```
 FROM_UNIXTIME(assignment.cutoffdate, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')
```

will display `01-01-1970 02:00`.
How can I display  an empty string or some text like 'not available'
in such cases? please note that using a "where date is not null" 
condition will not do because a need all results, including those with null in date fields.

Answer (score 0):

just use an `IF` statement:

```
IF(assignment.cutoffdate IS NULL, 'not available', FROM_UNIXTIME(assignment.cutoffdate, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i'))
```